# SQL MERGE with variable number of values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, sql-merge

I would like to know if a MERGE statement could, somehow, be written to support value sets with different column counts?

First, if we had a table that is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [Example]
(
  [Id] NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  [Name] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  [Format] NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT('yyyy-MM-dd')
)
```

Is it somehow possible to create a single MERGE statement which supports entries with and without the format column?
Can the following be adjusted to work?

```
MERGE [Example] AS t
USING
(
  VALUES
  ('id1', 'England', 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
  ('id2', 'Germany'), -- The expectation is that the default value would be used
  ('id3', 'America', 'MM.dd.yyyy')
) AS s([Id], [Name], [Format])
ON
  s.[Id] = t.[Id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    t.[Name] = s.[Name],
    t.[Format] = s.[Format]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ([Id], [Name], [Format])
    VALUES (s.[Id], s.[Name], s.[Format]);
```

This doesn't work because the Germany entry only has 2 values, which does not match the defined column count. I've tried adding `('id2', 'Germany', NULL)` but that inserts a `NULL` and not the default value defined for the column. I've also tried adding `('id2', 'Germany', DEFAULT)` but that failed with a Syntax error.

Is what I'm after possible? The only solution I have so far is to maintain two separte MERGE statements, one with the Format column, one without - is there any way to bring them together?

Comment: No - according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) you can only supply DEFAULT keyword for an `insert` not `merge`. You know the default value though so just use it in your values constructor?

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand interesting links - I haven't read them all, but what I did look at was interesting. As far as the locking/racing issues, this MERGE will only be run during DB installs (or updates), so all other _processes_ will be offline.

Comment: Hi @Stu, the final MERGE has over 200 entries, so I was hoping to avoid having to provide the same value over and over again...

Comment: Then perhaps use separate update and insert steps where you are able to use the *default* in a values constructor?

Comment: One option is use `VALUES (s.[Id], s.[Name], ISNULL(s.[Format], YourDefaultHere)`. You could use a variable there if you want